# Construct a direct graph on n vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I want to construct a digraph based instruction below :

For each $n \ge 2$, construct a digraph on n vertices such that 〖deg〗^+ (v)≠〖deg〗^+ (u) and 〖deg〗^- (v)≠〖deg〗^- (u) for all vertices $v\ne u$.
I know how to find 〖deg〗^+ (v)and 〖deg〗^- (v) but i don’t know how to find 〖deg〗^+ (u)and 〖deg〗^- (u).

Help me to construct the digraph based of the instruction ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the penultimate sentence. How does finding $\deg^+(u)$ differ from finding $\deg^+(v)$? Aren't $v$ and $u$ just variables that stand for arbitrary vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example is given by a transitive tournament, i.e. for $n\geq 2$ you have vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and you create edge $v_iv_j$ if and only if $j>i$.

Then for each $i$ the indegree of $v_{i}$ is $i-1$ and the outdegree is $n-i$, so both indegree and outdegree are different for different vertices.

Example: for $n=4$ we have vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$
and edges $v_1v_2,v_1v_3,v_1v_4,v_2v_3,v_2v_4,v_3v_4$.

On request: $d^-(v_1)=0,d^-(v_2)=1,d^-(v_3)=2,d^-(v_4)=3$,
$d^+(v_1)=3,d^+(v_2)=2,d^+(v_3)=1,d^+(v_4)=0$

Comment: A construction is given in the answer already and I don't see how to improve it, but I have added an example.

Comment: @Lin: This question does not make any sense. It looks like you have problems understanding what your original question means. $u$ and $v$ are just variables. Try to get a grasp of the concept of variable. I am afraid I am not the right person to help you with that.

Comment: @Lin: I have added it for the example. You need the general case though, and that is already in the answer: $d^-(v_i)=i-1$ and $d^+(v_i)=n-i$.

Comment: Yours are wrong. Example: the edges $v_1v_4,v_2v_4,v_3v_4$ cause $d^-(v_4)=3$.